# Removing a row in a numpy recarray

Tags: python, numpy, recarray

Is there a convenient way to delete a row containing some value in a recarray?  Say I have the following array,

```
a=numpy.array([(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), (4.0, 5.0, 10.0),(1.0,10.0,4.0)], 
dtype=[('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8'), ('C', '<f8')])
```

And I wanted to remove all rows with 10 in the B column so that the output is

```
([(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), (4.0, 5.0, 10.0)], 
dtype=[('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8'), ('C', '<f8')])
```

Is there a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pull out the relevant rows of the original array:

```
new_a = a[a["B"]!=10.0]
```